# PhpStorm warning - Cannot resolve directory - a href without file extension

Tags: php, phpstorm

I have PHP files and a href links that lead to these files but without the file extension. PhpStorm outputs the messages "Can not resolve directory. This inspection checks unresolved file references".
Example:

```
File path: /account.php
<a href="/account/">...</a>
```

Is in PhpStorm any setting to resolve this problem?

Comment: Nope, unless you disable such inspection. But next version (2016.2) will finally have some URL Rewriting support.

Answer (score 9):

New versions of PhpStorm can map Resources directories (Resource root) as well as other types (Tests, Sources, Excluded). Go to `File > Settings > Directories` (GNU/Linux, Windows), or `PhpStorm > Preferences > Directories` (`Ctr+Alt+S`) and select your Resource root directory.

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/directories.html (as 2016.3 is the current version at time).

Answer (score 2):

Preferences > Editor > Inspections > HTML > inspections > File reference problems [*disable*]